# TextField causing PageView to scroll up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a fairly convoluted widget tree which is causing a page view to go up when I submit a text field.

The effect: [PageView going up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrL9O.gif)

**My widget tree:**

StreamBuilder => Stack => Scaffold => PageView (horizontal) => StreamBuilder => FutureBuilder => PageView (vertical) => ChangeNotifierProvider => FutureBuilder => Scaffold => TextField

[Screenshot of widget tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCBgu.png)

**Attempted Solutions:**

Just creating the simplified tree:  PageView (horizontal) => PageView (vertical) => Scaffold => TextField does not produce this effect.

Listening to a PageView Listener on the second PageView shows same page/offset when the TextField causes it to go out of view.

Trying to animate/jump to the top of the page with a PageView Listener when the TextField is submitted does not stop this effect.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Are you using global keys in this widget?

Comment: I'm not, Ill try that @JustCase

Comment: Tried putting global keys in textfield, scaffold, and PageView. no luck. @JustCase

Comment: In fact, the use of global keys is dangerous, the improper use usually causes the complete reconstruction of the widget, so I asked, I already had a similar problem that was caused by global keys. If you can add an MVP of your code to investigate the cause of the problem.

Comment: @JustCase Im not really sure how to make an MVP. Is there a simple way to do it? or can you tell anything just  by the widget tree?

Comment: mpv is basic for running your screen or widget where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue I solved by putting this snippet `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in the `Scaffold`.